# Is there any android framework for sync data between local file and server?

Tags: android, frameworks

In my app, user get data from server, then I save these data to local file of phone, so same data don't need to load from server again. If there are some new messages send to user, these data need to load from server.
I intended to do it myself, but it seems this functionality is not so simple as I imagined. I think this is a common functionality, is there any framework focus on it? 
Please give me some guidance.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you read [Sync Adapter](https://developer.android.com/training/sync-adapters/creating-sync-adapter.html)

> The sync adapter component in your app encapsulates the code for the
>   tasks that transfer data between the device and a server. Based on the
>   scheduling and triggers you provide in your app, the sync adapter
>   framework runs the code in the sync adapter component.